# Coexisting JSF and JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, tiles

I have a java web project in which I use JSP, now I have to use jsf because I need a functionality wich cannot be provided by jsp only. The problem that I have is that I can't cohexist the two technologies into the same project, and I cannot re-code all what I already did using the jsp technology. Can someone help me in things I should do do merge the two technologies into the same project; I'm using spring, hibernate, tiles with maven, which explain the diffoculty that I have in trying to recode all what I did ;
here is parts of my configuration files:

from my web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

from my application-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.me.myproject" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
    <import resource="tiles-context.xml" />
```

from my spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

if I try to change the resolver by the JSF one, it doesn't work even with jsf pages

```
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
```

did someone have any idea what I have to do, thank you

Comment: Why can't you co-exist the two by putting them in different war files?  Then they get a different Spring config, right?

Comment: in my configuration files, I can't specify the two viewResolvers, in fact; if I use them both a time, nothing seems to run as it should,

Comment: thank you @JeanneBoyarsky for correcting english errors that I have in my post, and i'm sorry for my bad english; I don't know by the way how to remove this post to let only the correct one :s

Comment: You're welcome and it is ok to have a comment.  I'm wondering about having the two view resolvers in different war files/apps.  But not positive.  So hoping cleaning up the post would help someone else provide a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get It, the solution that I made to coexist the two technologies into the same project is by redirections, in fact, I add a file which redirect from a jsp to jsf file or from a jsf to a jsf file, after the redirection, the target page (a jsf one for example) is managed by his own controller ( the managed bean in the case of jsf ).